# Change Navigation Drawer background color for the selected item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I know this question has been repeated quite a few times but i tried every way and still there was no success in getting the desired result.
I just want the background of selected item to get changes when user clicks on it.
The code i have used is :

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

`public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(viewType==1){
        View itemLayout =   layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_layout,null);
        return new ViewHolder(itemLayout,viewType,context);
    }
    else if (viewType==0) {
        View itemHeader = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_layout,null);

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(position!=0){
        holder.navTitle.setText(titles[position - 1]);
        holder.navIcon.setImageResource(icons.getResourceId(position-1,-1));
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return titles.length+1;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position==0)return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

}
`<br><br>
activity_main.xml`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/containerView">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        />

</FrameLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    />
```

`<br><br>
MainActivity.java`
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Toolbar toolbar;
public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
String navTitles[];
TypedArray navIcons;
RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewAdapter;
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Let's first set up toolbar
    setupToolbar();

    //Initialize Views
    recyclerView  = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerMainActivity);

    //Setup Titles and Icons of Navigation Drawer
    navTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navDrawerItems);
    navIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.navDrawerIcons);



    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(navTitles,navIcons,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    setupDrawerToggle();
    Fragment FirstFragment = new FirstFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, FirstFragment, null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

void setupToolbar(){
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}

void setupDrawerToggle(){
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name);
    //This is necessary to change the icon of the Drawer Toggle upon state change.
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

}`

Comment: This is a lot of code. Would you kindly condense it into a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Done. Included just the minimum files and code required to understand the approach i used.

Comment: could you please edit the code snippets to play nicer with Stack Overflow's [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)? There are some mismatched braces that should be fixed.